# How to start the Windows shell/desktop (explorer.exe) if the computer has been started with a custom "Winlogon" shell (different than explorer.exe)?

Tags: windows-10, kiosk, windows-shell, winlogon.exe

For a kiosk application, I need to **not** start the Windows desktop/start menu on boot, but rather, a custom application instead. I set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`
to `c:\myapp\myapp.exe` and it works.

But occasionnally, I need to run the Windows desktop / start menu anyway, after having booted on my kiosk app. So I do <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ESCAPE</kbd> to run the Task Manager, then I run a new task from `File > New task`, then `explorer.exe`. I tried both with "Run with admin privilege" checkbox checked or not.

**It works: the Windows desktop appears** but  there are a few corner cases, see for example [Can't access the Device manager from Start menu, but working from Control panel, on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1759040/cant-access-the-device-manager-from-start-menu-but-working-from-control-panel).

**Question: how to start explorer.exe (the windows desktop + start menu, i'm not speaking of the file explorer) with the same parameters as the login process?**

Linked question (but does not solve): [How to launch the Windows Explorer shell after starting with a different one?](https://superuser.com/questions/644459/how-to-launch-the-windows-explorer-shell-after-starting-with-a-different-one)